# bbPress and Wordpress integration please login to post

Tags: php, wordpress, bbpress

I have integrated bbPress with Wordpress and it works fine on the development server but when I moved to production server, it is now asking me to log on before posting new topic even though I was logged on in Wordpress side. I didn't have to log on separately with development server to post in the forum.

Is there something I need to change?

**EDIT:**

**I found the answer! I had to add www in front of meta_value for url under object_type bb_option under bbpress_meta table!!!**

Answer (score 1):

It could be a cookie issue.

Make sure you have both installations set the cookie domain to be `.yoursite.com` - notice the `.` at the start, and the path to be `/`

Comment: Sorry but where do you find cookie?

Comment: Check the config files and the settings pages for both WordPress and bbPress, there should be something in there somewhere if not I'm not sure where it would be.